# Issues with Browserify and NodeJS Integration in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, npm, browserify

I'm having issues with developing my Google Chrome extension. I need some specific npm modules in order to execute my code so I looked into Browserify. I followed all the steps without issue but the code still produces errors when run. The screenshot is attached below.

[Error when Chrome extension is only loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2jj0.png)

All my files are located in the same project folder (popup.html, popup.js, bundle.js, etc.). I only have one html file and one javascript file (excluding bundle.js).
Here is my popup.html code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var convertMP3Button = document.getElementById("getLinkAndConvert");
 convertMP3Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { // 'tab' has all the info

   var fs = require('fs');
   var ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
   var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
   var ffmetadata = require("ffmetadata");
   var request = require('request');

   console.log(tab.url);       //returns the url
   convertMP3Button.textContent = tab.url;

   var url = tab.url;

    var stream = ytdl(url);
      //.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/Users/nishanth/Downloads/video.mp4'));

    // Helper method for downloading
    var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
      request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
      });
    };

   ytdl.getInfo(url, function(err, info) {
      console.log("INFO: " + JSON.stringify(info, null, 2));
      var process = new ffmpeg({source:stream})
      process.save('/Users/nishanth/Downloads/' + info.title + '.mp3').on('end', function() {
        console.log("PROCESSING FINISHED!");
        download(info.thumbnail_url, "/Users/nishanth/Downloads/image.jpg", function() {
          console.log("DOWNLOADED IMAGE");
          var options = {
            artist: info.author,
            attachments: ["/Users/nishanth/Downloads/image.jpg"]
          };
          ffmetadata.write('/Users/nishanth/Downloads/' + info.title + '.mp3', {}, options, function(err) {
            if (err)
              console.error("Error writing cover art: " + err);
            else
              console.log("Cover art added");
          });
        });
      });
    });

  });
 });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Youtube Music</title>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Youtube Music</h1>
    <button id="getLinkAndConvert">Download Song Now!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

It would be great if I could find out the reason why I have not been able to properly integrate browserify in order to use the npm modules.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't allow you to access the file system, instead they usually have some storage mechanisms of their own (cookies, [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), or a browser-specific system like [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)). Browserify has no way of getting around this, and doesn't provide a shim for `require('fs')`. Instead of writing directly to disk you'll need to have your app provide a downloadable version of your files, which the user will then have to save manually. If you don't need the files to be accessible outside the extension you can use the api I linked earlier, or drop in something like [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) which creates a virtual file system in the browser's storage.

Comment: I implemented your fix with browserify-fs, but I think the problem is with my ffmpeg library. Apparently, there are issues with child processes in the browser so the spawn function in the ffmpeg library doesn't work. I found it here: https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/175.

Comment: Yeah it's not really possible to spawn child processes in the browser. The closest thing is WebWorker. Remember, browserify doesn't actually let you run node.js code in the browser, it's just a pre-packager for commonjs modules with some built in shims.